# set start and end position in google roads API using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, directions, google-roads-api

I want to know if setting start and end location in the map while I'm retrieving coordinates and placeId through google roads API is possible or not? Because while I initialize Roads API by setting a custom coordinate like:

```
var mapOptions = {
                            zoom: 17,
                            center: {lat: -33.8667, lng: 151.1955}
                        };
```

its shows me a specific location in the map where the coordinate exists. But I want to initialize a map where I set a start and end location in the map and then start to use snapToRoads API to retrieve coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have done a little bit digging and solved it by myself.

The Javascript Part:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
                            <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing,places"></script>

                            <!--Elevation JS    
                        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>-->

                            <script>

                            //GOOGLE_API_KEY
                            var apiKey = 'GOOGLE_API_KEY';
                            alert("Provide GOOGLE API KEY");
                            var map;
                            var elevator;
                            var directionsDisplay;
                            var directionsService;
                            var drawingManager;
                            var placeIdArray = [];
                            var polylines = [];
                            var snappedCoordinates = [];

                            var initialLocation;
                            var siberia = new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105);
                            var newyork = new google.maps.LatLng(40.69847032728747, -73.9514422416687);
                            var browserSupportFlag =  new Boolean();

                            function initialize()
                            {
                                var mapOptions = {
                                    zoom: 17,
                                    center: {lat: -33.8667, lng: 151.1955}
                                };

                                directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
                                var polylineOptionsActual = new google.maps.Polyline({
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.6,
            strokeWeight: 2
            });
                                directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({polylineOptions: polylineOptionsActual});
                                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
                                directionsDisplay.setMap(map);


                                // Create an ElevationService
                                elevator = new google.maps.ElevationService();
                                // Adds a Places search box. Searching for a place will center the map on that
                                // location.
                                map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP].push(

                                document.getElementById('bar'));

                                var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocStart'));                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
                                                                                                                                                        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
                                                                                                                                                                         var placeStart = autocomplete.getPlace();
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  //alert(placeStart.place_id);
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          document.getElementById("startPlaceId").value=placeStart.place_id;

                                                                               });
                                                                                                                                                                var autocomplete1 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocEnd'));                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                        autocomplete1.bindTo('bounds', map);
                                                                                                                                                        autocomplete1.addListener('place_changed', function() {

                                                var placeEnd = autocomplete1.getPlace();
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  //alert(placeEnd.place_id);
                                                                                                                                                                                                          document.getElementById("endPlaceId").value=placeEnd.place_id;                                                                                                            

                                                    }); 


                                                                                                                                                             // Enables the polyline drawing control. Click on the map to start drawing a
                                                                                                                                                                     // polyline. Each click will add a new vertice. Double-click to stop drawing.
                                                                                                                                                                     drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
                                                                                                                                                                                                                             drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,
                                                                                                                                                                                                                             drawingControl: true,
                                                                                                                                                                                                                             drawingControlOptions: {
                                                                                                                                                                                                                             position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
                                                                                                                                                                                                                             drawingModes: [
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            ]
                                                                                                                                                                                                                             },
                                                                                                                                                                                                                             polylineOptions: {
                                                                                                                                                                                                                             strokeColor: '#696969',
                                                                                                                                                                                                                             strokeWeight: 2
                                                                                                                                                                                                                             }
                                                                                                                                                                                                                             });
                                                                                                                                                                                                                             drawingManager.setMap(map);

                                                                                                                                                                                                                             // Snap-to-road when the polyline is completed.
                                                                                                                                                                                                                             drawingManager.addListener('polylinecomplete', function(poly) {
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        var path = poly.getPath();
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        polylines.push(poly);
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        placeIdArray = [];
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        runSnapToRoad(path);
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        });

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        // Clear button. Click to remove all polylines.
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        $('#clear').click(function(ev) {
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          for (var i = 0; i < polylines.length; ++i) {
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          polylines[i].setMap(null);
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          }
                                                                                                        polylines = [];
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ev.preventDefault();

                     return false;
});
                        }

                    // Snap a user-created polyline to roads and draw the snapped path
                    function runSnapToRoad(path) {
                        var pathValues = [];
                        for (var i = 0; i < path.getLength(); i++) {
                            pathValues.push(path.getAt(i).toUrlValue());
                        }

                        $.get('https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads', {
                              interpolate: true,
                              key: apiKey,
                              path: pathValues.join('|')
                              }, function(data) {
                              processSnapToRoadResponse(data);
                              drawSnappedPolyline();
                              //getAndDrawSpeedLimits();
                              });
                    }

                    // Store snapped polyline returned by the snap-to-road method.
                    function processSnapToRoadResponse(data)
                    {
                        snappedCoordinates = [];
                        placeIdArray = [];


                        for (var i = 0; i < data.snappedPoints.length; i++) 
                        {
                            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
                                                                data.snappedPoints[i].location.latitude,
                                                                data.snappedPoints[i].location.longitude);
                                                                //getElevation(latlng);
                                                                snappedCoordinates.push(latlng);
                                                                placeIdArray.push(data.snappedPoints[i].placeId);

                        }

                        //get Altitude in meters
                        getElevation(snappedCoordinates);
                        document.getElementById("snappedCoordinatesArray").value=snappedCoordinates;                            
                        document.getElementById("snappedPaceIdArray").value=placeIdArray;


                    }

                    // Draws the snapped polyline (after processing snap-to-road response).
                    function drawSnappedPolyline() {
                        var snappedPolyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
                                                                       path: snappedCoordinates,
                                                                       strokeColor: 'black',
                                                                       strokeWeight: 3
                                                                       });

                                                                       snappedPolyline.setMap(map);
                                                                       polylines.push(snappedPolyline);
                    }

                    // Gets speed limits (for 100 segments at a time) and draws a polyline
                    // color-coded by speed limit. Must be called after processing snap-to-road
                    // response.
                    function getAndDrawSpeedLimits() {
                        for (var i = 0; i <= placeIdArray.length / 100; i++) {
                            // Ensure that no query exceeds the max 100 placeID limit.
                            var start = i * 100;
                            var end = Math.min((i + 1) * 100 - 1, placeIdArray.length);

                            drawSpeedLimits(start, end);
                        }
                    }

                    // Gets speed limits for a 100-segment path and draws a polyline color-coded by
                    // speed limit. Must be called after processing snap-to-road response.
                    function drawSpeedLimits(start, end) {
                        var placeIdQuery = '';
                        for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
                            placeIdQuery += '&placeId=' + placeIdArray[i];
                        }

                        $.get('https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/speedLimits',
                              'key=' + apiKey + placeIdQuery,
                              function(speedData) {
                              processSpeedLimitResponse(speedData, start);
                              }
                              );
                    }

                    // Draw a polyline segment (up to 100 road segments) color-coded by speed limit.
                    function processSpeedLimitResponse(speedData, start) {
                        var end = start + speedData.speedLimits.length;
                        for (var i = 0; i < speedData.speedLimits.length - 1; i++) {
                            var speedLimit = speedData.speedLimits[i].speedLimit;
                            var color = getColorForSpeed(speedLimit);

                            // Take two points for a single-segment polyline.
                            var coords = snappedCoordinates.slice(start + i, start + i + 2);

                            var snappedPolyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
                                                                           path: coords,
                                                                           strokeColor: color,
                                                                           strokeWeight: 6
                                                                           });
                                                                           snappedPolyline.setMap(map);
                                                                           polylines.push(snappedPolyline);


                                                                          //passDataToObjC();

                        }
                    }

                    function getColorForSpeed(speed_kph) {
                        if (speed_kph <= 40) {
                            return 'purple';
                        }
                        if (speed_kph <= 50) {
                            return 'blue';
                        }
                        if (speed_kph <= 60) {
                            return 'green';
                        }
                        if (speed_kph <= 80) {
                            return 'yellow';
                        }
                        if (speed_kph <= 100) {
                            return 'orange';
                        }
                        return 'red';
                    }


                    function getElevation(snappedCoordinatesArr)
                    {
                      var locations = [];

                      // Retrieve the latlng and push it on the array
                      for (var i = 0; i < snappedCoordinatesArr.length; i++) 
                        {
                            locations.push(snappedCoordinatesArr[i]);
                        }



                      // Create a LocationElevationRequest object using the array's one value
                      var positionalRequest = 
                      {
                        'locations': locations
                      }
                      //alert(positionalRequest);

                      // Initiate the location request
                      elevator.getElevationForLocations(positionalRequest, function(results, status) 
                      {
                        if (status == google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK) 
                        {

                          // Retrieve the first result
                          if (results) 
                          {
                              var altitudeArr=[];

                              for(var j=0;j<results.length;j++)
                              {
                                  altitudeArr.push(results[j].elevation);

                              }
                              document.getElementById("altitudeArray").value=altitudeArr;
                              document.getElementById("dataDisplay").style.display="block";
                              //alert(altitudeArr);
                          } 
                          else 
                          {
                            alert('No results found');
                          }
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                          alert('Elevation service failed due to: ' + status);
                        }
                      });
                    }

                    function calcRoute() 
                    {
                      var start = document.getElementById("autocStart").value;
                      var end = document.getElementById('autocEnd').value;

                      //alert(start);
                      var request = {
                          origin:start,
                          destination:end,
                          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
                      };
                      directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                          directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                        }
                      });
                    }

                    $(window).load(initialize);

                        </script>
```

And The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
                    <head>
                    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
                    <meta charset="utf-8">
                    <title>Roads API</title>
                    <style>
html, body, #map {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
#panel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -180px;
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
#bar {
    width: 240px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    margin: 8px;
    padding: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
#autoc {
    width: 98%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
</style>

<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="bar">
<form id="geodata-form" action="http://wayzme.sulavmart.com/map/savedata"> 
                      <div id="dataDisplay" style="display:none;">

    CoordinatesArray:
    <input type="text"  id="snappedCoordinatesArray" />
    AltitudeArray:  
    <input type="text"  id="altitudeArray" />
    PaceIdArray:    
    <input type="text" id="snappedPaceIdArray" />
    <input type="hidden" id="startPlaceId" />
    <input type="hidden" id="endPlaceId" />
  </div>
                      <p class="auto">
    <input type="text" id="autocStart" style="width:98% !important" name="start" />
  </p>
                      <p class="auto">
    <input type="text" id="autocEnd" style="width:98% !important" name="end"/>
  </p>
                      <input type="button" value="Get Directions" onClick="calcRoute();">

                      </form>
                      <p><a id="clear" href="#">Click here</a> to clear map.</p>
                    </div>

</body>
</html>
```